# Maintaining a 40% CO₂ aqueous environment?

Tags: aqueous-solution

I wish to grow algae in a 40% $\ce{CO2}$ (water under air with 40% $\ce{CO2}$ content) aqueous environment.

Simple DIY methods are available, but they are generally unreliable ([For more info on DIY read here](http://www.theplantedtankfaq.com/CO2_FAQ.html#)) because they rely on a [pH/KH chart](http://www.theaquatools.com/co2-calculations).

Atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ levels are measured based on [IR absorbency](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/ccgg/about/co2_measurements.html). However, such measurements are difficult and "complicated by the temperature signal generated by carbon dioxide as well as by the [signatures of ozone and water vapor](http://airs.jpl.nasa.gov/story_archive/Measuring_CO2_from_Space/History_CO2_Measurements/)."

Is there a reliable way to measure the $\ce{CO2}$ concentration that is relatively inexpensive (under $1,000)? Is the [drop checker method](http://www.aquaticplantenthusiasts.com/co2/4-drop-checker-revealed.html) reliable?

Comment: ergh. Please, clarify: do you need 40 weight % water solution of $CO_2$, water under air with 40% of $CO_2$ with atmospheric pressure or something else?

Comment: there are companies, providing industrial-level solutions. Home-brew solution should include arduino board, $CO_2$ gas cylinder, $CO_2$ sensor and electronically controlled valve.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel that the answer you desire could be a hair too involved to set up a home-made system which appears to be your desire in this case. I can guarantee you a wide family of correct answers to your problem await via a quick google search, but, and **please** understand that I only wish to help here, I fear that two sentences and a bounty are not a significant step towards what is likely an in-depth solution of the many out there. I wish you the best of luck however, and hope you revise your question soon.